# Automate docker for running test script

Tags: bash, docker, automation, docker-compose

I have three docker files with entry point bash files for each image. Each docker file is for different purpose like:

1. Dockerfile 1: - This file is to create the image and run the container which pulls my project repository and make it available to my host directory.
2. Dockerfile 2: - This file is to create the image and run the container which creates a jar file from my existing project code and make it available to my host directory.
3. Dockerfile 3: - This file is to create the image and run the container which uses created jar file and runs the test cases.

Now I want to automate this whole process using docker-compose or any other available options with docker. Can anyone guide me how to automate this all three separate process so that i can easily automate the process from pulling project code to running my test cases using jar file created in between. Can i get any article related to it or Docker-compose example files.

Comment: If the goal of the first two tasks is "make it available to my host directory", that sounds like you want to run Git and Maven/Gradle on your host system, not in Docker.  In any case you should be able to use a shell script to do this pretty straightforwardly (Compose isn't great for running a sequence of transient containers.)  What have you already tried, and what issues are you encountering?

Comment: instead of installing git and maven i want to use docker image, for that purpose i am using docker. running first image will give me latest code of my repository and second will create jar file. I have divided both task in separate because i need to use first image for different cases like to deploy my application or for any purpose which will act as input for other docker image. In this case i want to automate running test script by utilising three corresponding containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like can get you started. [Reference document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#build)

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  app-1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /path/to/Dockerfile1
    command: <something>
  app-2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /path/to/Dockerfile2
    command: <something>
  app-2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /path/to/Dockerfile3
    command: <something>
```

Comment: OK. This seems a fine approach let me try it.